# Small sample, many observations. Is the sample large enough?

Tags: regression, time-series, small-sample

I am working on a project regarding the influence of temperature and other variables on the sales of 3 branches of one local bakery. The research goal is to be able to better predict bakery sales (in my city) and to save food in this way.

What data do I have?
I do have the data of all variables for more than 3 years (>1000 days) and I don't want to know anything about the difference in sales between the different branches but get an average of all 3 branches normalized sales data.

What's the question?
The goal is to get evidence for the whole population of the bakeries in my city (so far by mainly using multiple linear regression). But since the sample size is not big enough (there are at least 100 branches of bakeries from all bakery companies) and the data is from just 3 branches of one of many companies it's at best a convenience sample for this population.

So I was wondering if I can call it a representative sample for all bakeries of the company providing the data (they have 30 branches--out of the 100 in the city--and it's a random sample)? If not so how would you call the sample for the population of all bakeries and the population of the companies bakeries?

Comment: Do you have 3, 30, or 100 branches? This isn't really clear. Your data are from 3 years, do you have the same data (eg sales) on each unit (eg a bakery) for every day over that time? If so, you should use time-series methods to address the serial correlation, not multiple regression.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I have the normalized data of sales for 3 branches, while the total population of branches in the city is ca. 100 and the total population of branches of the company that owns the 3 branches is 30. Yes I have the same data for each bakery for the same time period of 3 years (normalized values). The weather data is applicable to all bakeries since they are all located in one city. So far I used the avergage sales of those 3 bakeries as the dependent variable and e.g. temperature, air-pressure etc. as independent variables in a multiple regression model

Comment: If that's not the right method I'd be very happy about suggestions of better methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample will be representative if your sample attributes are representative. For example, temperature and weather are representative attributes, since they are similar for all branches in the town. But the price of rolls is not representative. Other branches can have prices much higher or lower than prices in those three branches used for prediction. In that case the extrapolation takes place, which is risky procedure and can result in significant prediction error. So the answer depends on what covariates are you using. You should think whether ranges of your covariates are enough to stay with interpolation. And, as Mr. @gung have nicely pointed out, time-series models are highly recommended in order to make successful predictions.